# How long does it take to get an account deleted?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I requested for a deletion of my account for Physics.SE, cf. [this help page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account). It's been more than six hours and apparently no action has been taken yet. Can anyone tell me how long a deletion process normally needs to finish?

Comment: Would you mind if I ask you, why you want to get your account deleted?

Comment: [Status completed](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/20719).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone at Stack Exchange HQ will need to verify and process your request, so you will probably need to wait *at least* until Monday during business hours.

Comment: Thanks a lot...